# Hide "related" links from external search engines to improve search results

Tags: feature-request, search

The "related questions" list displayed next to our questions leads to irrelevant hits in search engines. It is necessary to hide the "related" column from external search engines to get rid of those irrelevant links.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. Care to expand your question a bit?

Comment: @YannisRizos I think he means that the list of related questions leads to irrelevant hits in search engines.

Comment: For which no evidence is given at all.. Some examples would help this question, otherwise I'm voting to close it as not-a-question.

Comment: @MadScientist Well, I've never seen it, if anything it's the opposite.

Comment: Mad Scientist, you are right.

Comment: Logically, for this to be a problem the contents in the related box would have to be incorrect or inaccurate. So it's not a problem with Google.. it's a problem with the related content

Answer (score 7):

Who says it is necessary?

First, who says search results of external search engines needs improvement? Are you aware of the frequent situation where someone searches Google to find information to answer a new question, and finds *that question itself* as one of the highest-rated results?

Second, what's to say that those related posts don't actually *help*, by providing more context? (They are, after all, "Related"... not "nonrelevant"(sic)

In short; I think your premise is incorrect from the start.

Comment: All "related" articles are indexed in their turns. Additional links to them ("related" articles) will not help the user, but will oppositely fog the links the user actually searching for.

Comment: @KonstantinL Is that something you've observed? And if so, can you please provide a couple of examples? Obviously the related questions are indexed, but "fog the links the user actually searching" they do not... They are _related_ questions after all, at least some of them should be relevant to what you're actually searching for.

Comment: @KonstantinL The additional links to related articles most *certainly* helps me, the user, every day. As for 'fogging the links', I echo Yannis there.

Comment: Example #1:
Search in Google: "metro appbar localization".
Third result has nothing with localization but shown in the search result just because of the link in "Related".

Comment: @KonstantinL Did you look at the totality of the results? Or that the word "local" is in the question in question?

Comment: @KonstantinL Hm? I'm only seeing one SO question in the first page of the results for "metro appbar localization" and it's relevant. I've switched to incognito mode to avoid Google's personalized searches, and I'm seeing the same results. The third result in both searches is a msdn link. Can you please update your question with examples, including links to your searches and perhaps screenshots?

Comment: @YannisRizos [This is the result KonstantinL refers to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565131/metro-listview-and-appbar-cooperation-the-simplest-possible-multiple-select-sce)

Comment: I see that the result #3 is less relevant than #4, #5 and so on.

Comment: @KonstantinL I don't see that at all. #4 and #5 aren't related to Localization, either.

Comment: @KonstantinL The only question I see in the first page of results when searching for "metro appbar localization" is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055145/windows-8-metro-appbar-buttons-localization. Is "metro appbar localization" your exact search string? Again, if you update your question with links to your searches and screenshots of the results, it would be very helpful.

Comment: @KonstantinL Yes; what Yannis said; Please update the question with the information, rather than posting more in the comments here.

Answer (score -1):

From the site's POV, any hit from google that brings traffic is welcomed, so..

If you are talking about the hit-miss ratio of "related content" as a function of in-site navigation, then that would be a separate matter.

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but I'm not sure it addresses the question asked. The OP is suggesting that the list of "Related" posts to the right is causing false-matches in search engines.